# Xcode debug cannot capture view hierarchy on macbook M1

Tags: xcode, apple-m1, simulator, view-hierarchy

In one project, 'capture view hierarchy' and 'pause program execution' buttons are simply not working. 1 out of 20 times it's showing blank screen saying Unable to capture view hierarchy, but other times no response. Capturing memory graph button is working but it's taking forever to load. I have macbook with M1 chip with Xcode 13.3. Before that I had Xcode 13.3.1, which wasn't working as well. This situation is happening for one project only Tried to reinstall xcode-select, tried with different simulator ios versions, tried to run with Rosetta didn't work as well. For intel chips capturing works fine, it's only issue with M1. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're having trouble with an Xcode feature on M1, report it as a bug to Apple.